# Extract just file path from string

Tags: linux, string, bash

I have a file that contains strings in this format:

```
MD5 (TestImages/IMG_0627.JPG) = 6ed611b3e777c5f7b729fa2f2412d656
```

I am trying to figure out a way to extract the file path, so that I would get a string like this:

```
TestImages/IMG_0627.JPG
```

For a different part of my script, I am using this code to remove everything before and after the brackets, and I could of course do something similar, however I'm sure there is a better way?

```
shortFile=${line#*MD5 }
shortFile=${shortFile%%)*}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How about using sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sed` but that has the overhead of starting a new process.

```
echo $line | sed -r 's/MD5 \((.*)\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Running `sed` once: `sed -r 's/MD5 \((.*)\).*/\1/' <PATH/TO/FILE>`

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw a non-sed answer onto the pile. (Also slightly cheaper since it avoids the pipeline and sub-shell.)

```
awk -F '[()]' '{print $2}' <<<"$line"
```

That said the substring expansion option is a reasonable one if it does what you need. (Though it looks like you missed the `(` in the first expansion.)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/^.*(\([^)]*\)).*$/\1/' < infile.txt
```

Comment: I didn't at the time; I did now and updated to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way with cut can be :

```
echo $line|cut -d "(" -f2|cut -d ")" -f1
```